# Sharepoint people search - sort alphabetically accross pages

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts, paging

I have a Sharepoint 2007 MOSS People Search webpart, used with a Paging webpart to display search results of people.

The people search webpart displays results alphabetically on each page. But the results are not sorted alphabetically **across** pages.

Does anyone know anyway to acheive an alphabetical sort of people results accross pages, by changing the XSLT for e.g?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that works across pages has to be part of the search query, not the xsl. I think you only have relevance and social distance as sort options on the out of box search web parts, though it may be possible to get custom ordering using sql search syntax - possibly from the advanced search box.